# How do I tell wordpress that a template is an archive

Tags: wordpress, templates, archive

The use case is that I want to list the most recent posts on a page. Each post containing only the summary and title and a link to the full post.

I have created a template called Latest Posts and it loads ok. However I want get_content() to somehow understand that this template is an archive template and therefor only display the excerpt and not the full post.

I use the following "content" template for all other listings and would like to reuse it when listing my latest posts, but since it isn't either a search or an archive the first selection is skipped, and the_content() will show the whole post.

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
<div class="entry-summary">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-summary -->
<?php else : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'bbl' ) ); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'bbl' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any ideas? I've been looking around for ideas, and I've seen a lot of different ways to make archives, but I haven't been able to put it all together to fit my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use this code:

```
global $more;    // Declare global $more (before the loop).
....
$more = 0;       
....
```

More on this subject can be found in the documentation:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content#Overriding_Archive.2FSingle_Page_Behavior

Now the_content() will not show anything after the more-tag

It's not really telling the engine that this is an archive page, but only mimic the behaviour